# Solving equation with multiple unknowns in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, calculation

I am new to VBA so forgive me if my question is too ambiguous. I have a row in excel which takes inputs and finally calculates a sum. For instance, this could be taking user input in cells A1,B1,C1 and the calculation in the final cell would be:

```
D1 = A1*3 + B1*8 + C1*14
```

The twist is that instead of just inserting the values in cells A1:C1, I just have the value I should obtain in D1 and I need to find what the inputs should be in A1:C1. So in a nutshell I need to write a VBA program which decides what the inputs should be to obtain a solution as close to the value needed in D1 as possible.

I would really appreciate any ideas/code examples to get me started because currently I'm slightly stuck. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: That is not possible as there is more than one solution to the equation `d = 3a + 8b + 14c` if only `d` is given. So a code that gives you **the** solution does not exist. To find **one** of the solutions (or get close to one) you can use the Solver (see [Define and solve a problem by using Solver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040)) or use the [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). Also the question is if there are any side rules like `a`, `b` and `c` have to be integers.

Comment: To show you one problem here: For example if you don't define any secondary conditions (and just have this equation) then it is always possible to set `a = 0` and `b = 0` which reduces the equation to `d = 14c` which you can easly calculate like `c = d / 14` and you have a solution to the equation. Since that is probably not what you expected, that means your question is not precise enough.

Comment: Please give an example value of D1 and its calculated inputs A1, B1 & C1.

Comment: The comments are not right, it is possible to solve, however, there are multiple feasible solutions. You can take a look at the Excel Solver, which solves Linear Programs. In your case, you do not have an objectiv function as you are only looking for a feasible solution

Comment: @FloLie What is wrong? What you tell is exactly what I said: There is more than one solution. Actually there is an **infinite** amount of solutions. Therefore it is not solveable unless you have an infinite amount of time to calculate. And further I said if OP is just interested in any values that solve the equation that can easily be found. But mathematically solveable in the meaning of solving an equation is not possible (unless OP defines secondary conditions).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I did say that I need to obtain "a" solution and not "the" solution. There are no other conditions.

Comment: @Fedra Well that one I solved already `c = d / 14` and `a = b = 0`. But that is extremly likely not what you expected. So with the information you gave there will be infinite useless "solutions", but we cannot tell a useful one unless you define some secondary conditions. I tried to show that you have some problems because his question is not well defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure, your problem is more restricted than you are writing, because it does have a lot of degrees of freedom.

Example Solutions:

```
A1 = B1 = C1 = X
X = D1/(14+8+3) = D1/25
```

or

```
A1 = B1 = 0
-> C1 = D1
```

or you use the `Excel Solver` with no Objective Function to find any feasible solution.

Comment: Thank you very much I will look into it :)